# Hibernate create foreign key to itself

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have a very strange problem with hibernate at the moment. 
Somehow on a table, it create a foreign key which reference to itself. the column is also a primary key. This essentially prevent me from delete any row from that table.

In the log I could see a line:

> DEBUG org.hibernate.SQL - alter table Device add index
>   FK79D00A76C682495E (id), add constraint FK79D00A76C682495E foreign key
>   (id) references Device (id)

Other table with similar table seems fine. and this seems to be true for both MySQL and Derby. I'm using hibernate 4.1.4

the annotated class is as follow.

```
@Entity(name = "Device")
public class Device extends DomainObject implements Searchable {

    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
protected long id;

    @Column(name = "Type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private DeviceTypeEnum type = DeviceTypeEnum.AccessControlDevice;

    @Column(name = "Name", length = Constance.DATABASE_NAME_FIELD_LENGTH)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "Description", length = Constance.DATABASE_DESCRIPTION_FIELD_LENGTH)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "Identifier", length = Constance.DATABASE_IDENTIFIER_FIELD_LENGTH, unique = true)
    private String identifier;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "Device2Group", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "DeviceID")}, inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "DeviceGroupID")})
    private List<DeviceGroup> groups = new ArrayList<DeviceGroup>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "location")
    private Location location;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "Address")
    private Address address;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "Link", nullable = false)
    private Link link;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns out that in one of the Entity Class "Location" which the Device entity references, it has a `@ManyToMany` mapped collection of Device, where it really should be `@OneToMany`. 
After change the `@ManyToMany to @OneToMany` the constrain disappears.

Answer (score 0):

I see no references to `Device` class in your code. So I am assuming that this class has been modified, **but its table has not, because it has some data**. (Why else should it have a foreign-key to itself?)

Try dropping this table in your database to make hibernate create it once more, or set `p.hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `create-drop`.

Comment: the log is generated while hibernate export scheme. I have tried to drop database first but still same.

Comment: U are right though, it has been modified and it indeed had a self-reference in one column (a tree like structure), which i dropped. But i'm not sure why it happened and now even after add the column back, the constrains is still presented.

Comment: @Wudong when you drop the table (which needs to be empty first), hibernate does not find it in your schema. So it creates the table at the server start up. After these steps, your table must not have a foreign-key to itself. I'm asking 1)Have you dropped your table? 2)Has hibernate created it again? 3)Has it been created correctly?

Comment: 1) The database has been dropped, including all the table in it. 2) Yes. the foreign key constrain is created again when hibernate export the schema. 3) Still same. IMO, hibernate should never create such a foreign key constrain because it is invalid in any case I can think of.

Comment: Your class is inherited, isn't it the reason of this foreign-key? Have you checked the parent's table?

Comment: I have checked.. but no there are no JPA hibernation in the parent table. I'm now just wondering in which situation hibernate would generate a foreign key?

Comment: In case you have a relation with other entities (`OneToOne` or `ManyToOne`), hibernate would generate a foreign-key. Like your `Address` or `Location`. Do you have a hibernate configuration file, or you only use annotations? In the former case, you'd better check that cfg file as well.

Comment: Still, I cannot figure out why this happened. I see no relation defined to itself. I use annotation only. I would like to do some debug to see exactly how this happened, can you suggest which class in hibernate I should look at?